# How to use the split command to tackle a string from the back end

Tags: python, string, parsing, split

I'm trying to parse out different sections of a comma separated string.

Here are two example strings:

> Plant communities and soils in cryoturbated tundra along a bioclimate gradient in the Low Arctic, Alaska,Phytocoenologia, v.35, 2005, p. 761.
>
> Visualizing Frost Boils,Challenges in Science and Engineering, v.13, 2005, p. 18.

I need to store the page number, year, volume (v.13), journal, and title into separate variables. I would like to tackle these strings from the back because the title may have commas in it (planning on splitting on commas), and the back end of the strings is quite consistent. Any pointers on how to tackle this problem backwards would be very helpful. Thanks!

for the second example:

```
page = 'p.18'
year = '2005'
volume = 'v.13'
journal = 'Challenges in Science and Engineering' 
title = 'Visualizing Frost Boils'
```

Comment: There are a number of questions on SO that deal with reversing a string. That is why you are receiving downvotes I believe.

Comment: Not so much about reversing the string, as it is splitting from the right - str.rsplit(',', 4) is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

```
title,journal,vol,year,page = my_string.rsplit(',',4)
```

I think is what you want

Comment: I knew what you meant. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rsplit()`:

```
>>> s = 'Visualizing Frost Boils,Challenges in Science and Engineering, v.13, 2005, p. 18.'
>>> title, journal, volume, year, page = [entry.strip() for entry in  s.rsplit(',', 4)]
>>> page
'p. 18.'
>>> year
'2005'
>>> volume
'v.13'
>>> journal
'Challenges in Science and Engineering'
>>> title
'Visualizing Frost Boils'
```

You split your string starting form the right with `rsplit(',' 4)` at commas and limit the number of splits to 4.
The `entry.strip()` removes white space around the entries.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of commas is always the same, you could write a function to get the index of the various commas, and then return the strings between the indices.

For example, if we count that there are 4 commas, we'd have:

```
title = string[:comma_index1]
year = string[comma_index1:comma_index2]
volume = string[comma_index2:comma_index3]
year = string[comma_index3:comma_index4]
page = string[comma_index4:]
```

This is probably a naive way to do it though.

Comment: The rsplit method suggested by Mike Müller below is a much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Personally for this I would use regular expressions.

```
>>> import re
>>> c = re.compile('(.*), v.(\d*), (\d*), p. (\d*).')
>>> c.match('Plant communities and soils in cryoturbated tundra along a bioclimate gradient in the Low Arctic, Alaska,Phytocoenologia, v.35, 2005, p. 761.').group(1,2,3,4)

('Plant communities and soils in cryoturbated tundra along a bioclimate gradient in the Low Arctic, Alaska,Phytocoenologia', '35', '2005', '761')
```